# Issue in div's floats right in IE7

Tags: html, css

i have a problem in html and css. that's,check the div is in the below order

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">
   </div>
   <div class="child2">
   </div>
</div>

.child1 { float:right; width:auto; }
.child2 { float:right; width:200px; }
```

in this the div child1 is a horizontal growing div. so its not possible to add specific width to the div. what i need to show the child1 and child2 div in same horizontal line. if child1 is empty the child2 will be the rightmost div. the above solution don't work in ie7. please help me to find a solution.

please check this image.
[image: ie error]

- image 1: rendering in chrome
- image 2: rendering in ie7

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo showing the problem?

Comment: @Jaison Justus: It's just a typo I think. But you do know that class names in CSS are prepended with a dot (`.`) right?

Comment: @PeeHee i forget to add dot in the question.

Comment: @thirtydot: the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonjustus/hAEKk/

Comment: what made the "records in page" drop to the next line? what's the difference in the code?

Comment: @jackjoe their is no difference sorry i forget to tag the image. the first one is the rendering in chrome and the second one in ie7 for same css

Comment: what's the **width of the parent div** if it's fixed than probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: @ounit the width:100%. its also a floating div

Comment: @Jaison Justus: Your jsFiddle demo already appears to work in IE7. Please provide a demo where it's broken in IE7.

Comment: @thirtydot... let me check my css once more

Comment: thanks guys its actually my fault sorry. and thanks for everyones response.. a salute for all who tried to help me. have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

swap their order in the html.

Rigth floats are "inverted".

like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child2">
   </div>
   <div class="child1">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you have to define standard `doctype` like this  `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your html page

Comment: this is my doctype <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: My DOCTYPE in a HTML5 DOCTYPE with triggered the browser from quirk mode to standard mode